# How to create a <a> link dynamically from a javascript array inside a script tag?

Tags: javascript, script-tag

I am trying to create a 3  link with href and innerHTML from a JS array which is declared outside of the script tag. I am not sure how to pass the array into the script tag and use to create custom  elements.
Here is my JS array

```
    let linkArr = [
        {
            "name": "A sample URL", "url": "https://asampleurl.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "Another sample URL", "url": "https://anothersampleurl.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "A final sample URL", "url": "https://afinalsampleurl.com"
        }
    ]
```

Here is what I am trying
'''

```
<script link1Name=this.links[0].name, link1Href= this.links[0].url>

    var a = document.createElement("a");
    var link1Name = document.currentScript.getAttribute('link1Name');
    var text = document.createTextNode(link1Name);
    a.appendChild(text);
    a.href = link1Href ;
    var element = document.getElementById("links");
    element.appendChild(a);
        
</script>
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

First off, not sure what you are trying to do here:

```
<script link1Name=this.links[0].name, link1Href= this.links[0].url>
```

but, that is not valid HTML. You should just have: `<script> ... </script>`

To answer your question though, IF `linkArr` was declared globally, not inside some other function or locally scoped code, you should be able to reference it anywhere else in your document, so long as your script tag comes after it's declaration. `linkArr` will be available on the `window` if it was declared globally. You can easily test this by doing a `console.log(linkArr)` or `console.log(window.linkArr)` from your browser's console.

Finally, to create the links from that array, assuming you have access to it on the `window`, you should be able to do:

```
<script>
    var element = document.getElementById("links");
    linkArr.forEach(link => {
        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.innerText = link.name;
        a.href = link.url;
        element.appendChild(a);
    })
</script>
```